# how to make this kind of photo?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, technique

i would like to learn how to make this picture ; i tried double exposition technique but didnt succeed, pls can you help me pls? thanks ; what is the technique and method used to create it ?

i tried to find how to make it but i couldnt [image: double exposition]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an example of using [chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) technique. There T-shirt has some distinct color (say, bright neon blue) which in Photoshop or other editing program you can use to mark pixels to be transparent.

If this is done in studio with matching blue background, you get and image of the person with transparent body and surroundings. After that you overlay that image with separately taken image of the road.

Simpler approach is to use tripod and take two images of the road: with the person present (in any clothing) and without. Then overlay in Photoshop and mask shirt pixels from first image, hence making body "disappear"